# Webrequest looks identical but won't log in?

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest

Hello everyone I'm facing a bit of a problem that has had me stumped for about an hour. I'm trying to create an app to log in for my work schedule so I don't have to keep opening my web browser and check since my hours change so rapidly. I'm having a bit of an issue logging in though; currently I'm using a webclient to try to do so with my following class:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myTLC
{

    public class TLC
    {
        private String employeeID;
        private String password;
        private String employeeName;
        private List<String> values = new List<String>();

        public TLC(String ID, String password)
        {
            this.employeeID = ID;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String TLC_Login()
        {
            LoadValues();

            using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
                client.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
                client.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US");
                client.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "https://mytlc.bestbuy.com/etm/");
                client.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
                client.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");

                var parm = new NameValueCollection
                {
                    {"wbat", values[0] },
                    {"pageAction", "login" },
                    { "url_login_token", values[1]},
                    {"login", employeeID },
                    {"password", password },
                    {"localeSelected", "false" },
                    {"wbXpos", "0" },
                    {"wbYpos", "0" }
                };

               byte[] response_array = client.UploadValues("https://mytlc.bestbuy.com/etm/login.jsp", parm);
               return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response_array);
            }
        }

        public void LoadValues()
        {
            using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
            {
                String pageSource = client.DownloadString("https://mytlc.bestbuy.com/etm/");
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(pageSource);

                if (doc.ParseErrors != null && doc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
                {
                    //Error Handling - I'll add it later on.

                }

                String wbat = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//input[@id='wbat']").GetAttributeValue("value", "null");
                String url_token = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//*[@id='inforLoginWrappingDiv']/input").GetAttributeValue("value", "null");

                values.Add(wbat);
                values.Add(url_token);
            }
        }



        public String e_ID
        {
            get { return employeeID; }
            set { employeeID = value; }
        }

        public String e_Pass
        {
            get { return password; }
            set { password = value; }
        }

        public String e_Name
        {
            get { return employeeName; }
            set { employeeName = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

The request data (handled by Google Chrome and inspected in Fiddler) looks like this:

```
POST https://mytlc.bestbuy.com/etm/login.jsp HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: https://mytlc.bestbuy.com/etm/
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: mytlc.bestbuy.com
Content-Length: 167
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000HLkYnJDHq9wQwU8qPA90MYq:182bi51ql

wbat=yP6uE%2F7vW9xhvIPEm1Ro6h%2FQNEObayZ6&pageAction=login&url_login_token=-1959600643775&login=xxxx&password=xxxx&localeSelected=false&wbXpos=0&wbYpos=0
```

(Some numbers in login token are left out and username and pass are left out, for good reasons obviously)

What I can't figure out is what the issue is? I process my request through the `WebClient` class (That someone here on StackOverflow has posted before, credits to them) I grab all my values I need to pass correctly; I have made sure all the values are correctly being pulled, and I get no error on the login attempt all the program does is redirect back to the login page without any error messages.

Am I missing something in the request guys, or I am completely blind here?

I wouldn't think it would be anything with the .jsp? Meaning that they're using Java so that raw WebRequest wouldn't work because they can't pass Java / Javascript? That's my only thought on why it would not work.

Comment: Maybe they have authentication token. If you post without this token server will reject your request.

Comment: Here's all the parameters that the request is asking for (taken from Fiddler) maybe I missed something but it seems that all my parameters match the request: http://i.imgur.com/NUnoItr.png

Comment: They have token url_login_token this changes every get request. They are using this for prevent CSRF attacks. So before every post you should get this login page and get url_login_token value and post it. Otherwise your request will be rejected.

Comment: What about the GetValues() method, I'm calling that right before I do the POST, which contains that value?